# MySQL Replication based on geo-location

Tags: mysql, replication

We have a web app which is running in two different countries (Germany and USA).
For us it is very important to keep the data of our customers in the country where they belong so a german customer should stay in Germany and vice-versa.

I would like to migrate to a cloud solution and have 2 DBs instances (for speed purpose) based in the US and in Germany. 
The webapp is generating IDs with auto-increment and I would like the links to work in both directions.
So for example both links should work:

http://example.com/12.html

http://example.de/12.html

The two DB instances would be set as Master-Master replication but the issue is that I don't want the data generated in Germany to be replicated in the US DB.
Obviously this causes issue with the auto-increment IDs and I have no idea how to fix that.

Would appreciate if anyone could help me or guide me on how this scenario could be handled.

Comment: Why do you want to use replication when you don't want any data replicated?

Comment: Re the issue with links and IDs. In the example I gave both links should refer to the same object.

Comment: I don't understand your requirements here.

Comment: It was a business requirement. After further thoughts we opted for 2 separate databases without having any replications to keep the 2 business entities isolated. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your requirements. Can you please detail?

With the info that you have here I would suggest this:

In case you want to optimise for speed in a cloud infrastructure then you need to cache on the front end, use some CDN Service e.g. Amazon CloudFront, Google ... In this case the data is available on either side of the Atlantic but it is only cached temporarily and the data is not hosted there in the DB. You empty the front end cache and your data is not there anymore! So, you do not need DB replication at all! Keep your data where they belong and use a CDN implementation / Front End Cache on top of your web app / web service implementation!

In case you do not want to use these services but you want to host your own then you can implement a simple CDN / front end server by your own. It is quite simple, you need to query and cache the data for your pages and then store the pages with some data from the client. E.g. HTTP header region data, x-forwarded-for, regional data, some client cookie ... You can implement a simple app for this and then refer to the proper page on the fly...